# SonarQube downloading is failing

Tags: download, sonarqube

I am trying to downloading Sonarqube from below link but it is always failing after after some time. can some body please share me another link from where i can download it.

https://www.sonarqube.org/downloads/

Answer (score 2):

You can try downloading it from Maven Central if you constantly have issues with the official Website.

Just follow these steps:

- Open http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/sonarsource/sonarqube/sonar-application
- Go into the folder `x.y.z` that is the version you want to download ("6.3.1" for instance)
- Download the file called "sonar-application-`x.y.z`.zip"

Comment: So the problem is on your side!

Comment: Got the problem.  It has problem with Google Chrome with mozila it downloaded. Thanks